Why did Trinity decide to rescue the Mexican man?
In the opening scene of the movie, They Call Me Trinity (1970), we see that Trinity steps on to save a Mexican man from the bounty hunters.



How did Trinity know that the Mexican man was innocent and a candidate for rescue from the bounty hunters?

Who said he was innocent? Perhaps Trinity was just causing trouble...which is his MO

Since this is the opening scene of the movie, here are possible reasons:
a) Even if you take a general case if anyone sees a wounded man, their immediate priority is to save him instead of wasting time knowing whether the man is innocent or guilty. It seems the same thing happened to Trinity as well. (often called Instinct or Intuition)
b) We can also see the same thing with an angel of Morality. Based on morality, it seems He helped the Mexican man simply because it's the right thing to do, regardless of whether the man is innocent or guilty.
c) In a lot of Hollywood movies we see that the hero's intervention in an opening scene sets the tone for the character and the plot. The decision to rescue the Mexican man establishes Trinity as a heroic figure.
Trinity's exact reasoning for intervening can be based on any of the above factors mentioned, but it fits with his character's portrayal as a charismatic and unconventional hero.
One movie with a similar approach is The Dark Knight (2008). It starts with Batman saving a group of criminals from being robbed by a gang of masked assailants. As the film progresses, it clears out that some of the individuals Batman saved are not entirely innocent and their actions contribute to the chaos in Gotham City.
